# is it safe to use 31 for "last day of the month" when comparing dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I know this is not the perfect approach but is there a problem
when comparing dates in **MySQL** and other DBs to just use `Y-m-31` as 
the last day of the month?

For example

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE  date > 2015-02-01 AND date < 2015-02-31`

Comment: I can't see a problem with this strategy.

Comment: I don't understand your question. But are you looking something like this?   
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date_field >= '2015-02-01' AND date_field <= date_format(date_field,'%Y-%m-31')

Comment: Or else, are you looking something like this?,                                                   SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date between DATE_FORMAT(date ,'%Y-%m-01') AND  DATE_FORMAT(date ,'%Y-%m-31')

Comment: The advantage of this method over the others is that a range can use an index. A function cannot. Note that `2015-03-01 - INTERVAL 1 DAY` might be more satisfactory.

Comment: I was wondering that too, was going to either use MySQL for figuring out the last day but was hoping just setting to 31 would do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function for this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date >= '2015-02-01' AND date <= LAST_DAY('2015-02-01')
```

(you probably also want `>=` and `<=` instead of excluding the first/last days of each month)

Comment: I like your answer, this will require some change in the query builder .. but can work  :) Do you see any possible problems in my original code (except how it looks)?

Comment: @d.raev Your code may fail in some servers - there are flags to enable strict date checking that'd turn invalid dates into `0000-00-00` causing you to always return zero rows. If you're in full, permanent control of the server it looks pretty safe - MySQL seems to handle `2015-07-50` as `2015-07-31` in my MySQL installation (I was curious as to whether it'd wind up as `2015-08-19` or something).